# Push Notification to selected user

Tags: android, push-notification

I am writing a chat application.

A sends message to B.

B does not have my application running.

I want to send PushNotification (PN) to B saying, "Hello A just sent you a message".

**How can I do it?**

I know how to send PN to B when I know B's email used when B registered his android phone. I can force B to give me his email when registering my application, but I cannot be sure that he will give me the same email as the one used to register his phone.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a separated **service** that will remain running in the **background** checking for any new messages, even if the user finished the app.

See this official piece: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Or my preferred one: https://proandroiddev.com/deep-dive-into-android-services-4830b8c9a09

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want real Push Notification you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client